# To lower case using Find and Replace with regular expression in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using the Find and Replace function in Visual Studio 2010 in order to change the coding style for fields.

All instances similar to

```
m_MyField
```

should be

```
_myField
```

but I can only manage to get

```
_MyField
```

using

```
Find what:      m_{[a-zA-Z]}
Replace with:   _\1
```

How do I make the first letter lower case? I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
Find what:      m_{[a-zA-Z]}
Replace with:   _\L\1
```

I found this explained in http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Changing_case_with_regular_expressions but it only works for vim I think.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this approach:

```
Find what:      m_A{[a-zA-Z]}
Replace with:   _a\1
```

and repeat it for B..Z

Not elegant but should be done quick.