# Visual Studio / C# - Capitalizing all hexadecimal int literals?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, hex, literals

Recently I've began to convert a massive project from VB.net to C# using the language convert operation in SharpDevelop to get a bit of a head start. For some reason the converter insisted on taking all of our capitalized hexadecimal int literals:

```
&HDC8C60
```

and making them lowercase:

```
0xdc8c60
```

I would like to convert all of them to uppercase, like before:

```
0xDC8C60
```

The problem is that **there are hundreds of these literals in this project**. This is due to the fact that the project is heavily focused on memory modification and injecting x86 bytecode into one *specific* process with many specific offsets and values referenced. Because of this, I'd like to find a way to **capitalize them all at once**.

I looked everywhere in Visual Studio's editor settings, I looked through all of Visual Studio's `Edit` menu commands, I've searched both Google and Stack Overflow every which way. All I could find were questions asking about how to capitalize formatted hexadecimal *strings*.

If I have to use a program other than Visual Studio, that would be no problem as long as the program is free and I can do it to multiple source files at once.

Comment: You could use linqpad (free, but paid version is nice). Just loop through all your .cs files and look for the literals and change them.

Comment: Just how would Linqpad be of help here?

Comment: I suspect you could use Roslyn to do this, though it would take some effort.

Comment: what about reading the files with a console app, and every time you encounter a 0x[a-f0-9]+ to do a to upper? could put it as a pre-build step

Comment: @JonSkeet: What do you exactly mean by "I suspect you could use Roslyn to do this"? I know something smart is behind your comment. If you don't mind can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Transcendent: I mean that Roslyn is a compiler and code editor API. It would allow you to load a project, get the compiler to parse it, find all the hex literal tokens, rewrite them, then save the source files afterwards.

Comment: You could use visual studio find/replace with a regular expression. Though you'd have to find the correct regex and run it six times (once per a-f) since there's no change case functionality. Perhaps this could be a start https://stackoverflow.com/q/13601381/491907

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, and read your classes and pass the string to the method to convert all lowercase literals to uppercase:

```
public static String Convert(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
        if (i + 2 >= input.Length) {
            sb.Append(input[i]);
            break;
        }
        if (input[i] != '=' && input[i + 1] != '0' && (input[i + 2] != 'x' || input[i + 2] != 'X'))
        {
            sb.Append(input[i]);
        }
        else {
            String temp = String.Empty;
            while (input[i] != ';' && i < input.Length) {
                temp += char.ToUpper(input[i]);
                i++;
            }
            sb.Append(temp).Append(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

You can use it like:

```
String convertedClass = Convert(File.ReadAllText("SomeClass.cs"));
```

And then save it.